# xcodeproj file is missing

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have folder where i store all my projects. I have problem with one of them.
All projects except this have projectname.xcodeproj file.

When i open Xcode i see this project - it has icon with white background (other have blue background). I can open it, build and run.

I can't find this **.xcodeproj** file - so i can't run **pod init** in terminal for this folder. I See error "*No xcode project found, please specify one*".

I don't use git. Searching for this file had no results. What else can i do?

Comment: Maybe look in your trash?

Comment: @akashivskyy I didn't delete it

Comment: Well, it sure didn't disappear on its own. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have changed the path for the specific project you're experiencing problems with. Try to create another project and just copy/paste the files from the old project into the new one and reference the new project.

Comment: Thank you @David for editing. I try to improve my english skills :D